# Displaying a message when hover on a readonly attribute!

Tags: product, javascript, css, custom, jquery

I'm trying to display message on hover over a readonly select in a product page, 
( Magento 2.2.4, Php 7)

**Here's my attempt: 
CSS:**

```
#select_801[readonly]{
  background: #eee;
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery('#select_801 option[value=2561]').attr('selected','selected');
jQuery('#select_801').attr('readonly', true);
jQuery('#select_801').attr('data-title', 'This Element is disabled');
jQuery( "#select_801" ).hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('data-title').fadeIn(300);
});
```

I tried using tooltip but it said it's not a function on Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
//m1 is the parent div's class that contains the select.
//m1_pl is one of the select's options

     jQuery(function($) {
      var select = jQuery('.m1');
      jQuery('.m1_pl').prop('selected','true');
      select.hover(function() {
         jQuery(this).attr('title', 'This Element is disabled');
            jQuery('.m1').attr('readonly', true);
      });
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
   .m1 {
       cursor: not-allowed; }
    .m1 select {
       pointer-events:none; 
       background: #eee; }
```

**This would let the select Readonly, has a chosen option, and has a hover message.**

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery('#select_801 option[value=2561]').attr('selected','selected');
  var select = jQuery('#select_801');
  select.hover(function() {
     jQuery(this).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'This Element is disabled');
     jQuery('#select_801').attr('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

CSS Code:

```
#select_801[readonly]{
  background: #eee;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Pointer Event "none" was stopping the hover effect to trigger. It should work now.

JSfiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8vtcen6r/47/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to keep the select untouchable/"disabled" (readonly) and display a message on hover.

Comment: Please check my updated code.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sorry; I didn't want to disable the attribute because I still want it to be functional, I just don't want the user to touch it. Disabling it would make this line useless jQuery('#select_801 option[value=2561]').attr('selected','selected');. My goal is to select a default option for the dropdown, make it untouchable by the user and let the user know that it's untouchable by showing a hover message.

Comment: You want to make it Untouchable but still functional?

Comment: I want it to be readonly but not disabled. Because values of disabled inputs will not be submitted. I want the data to be submitted, which is the option I selected a default.

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Please check my answer, I managed to do that, but by using the parent div. Thanks for your help !